# Software that reads music file and returns vector of frequency and duration

Tags: open-source, software-development, audio

Good afternoon, guys, what's the good? I need to do a program that when reading a file.mp3 that returns its frequency and duration to a vector, preferably in the javascript language, or if you have a program that does that, someone recommends, p5.js, but always gives an error in

Comment: What do you mean with *returns its frequency and duration to a vector*? Does the program have to do some kind of Fourier analyis? What's in the MP3 files?

Comment: yes, in fact I'm putting together a project with arduino and I need to pass to a buzzer, a vector with tone (frequency, duration of the frequency) and in case I wanted to know if there is a program that reads a file.mp3 and returns this vector.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2O3nm0Nvbi4&t=349s < 
in this video, it does this but p5.js is no longer working the loadsound modules